# phpunit --version, on terminal, does not return anything

Tags: phpunit

I am new to phpunit and just installed it. To make it accessible globally, i moved it from my MAMP PHP5.5.3 bin to

```
/usr/local/bin
```

so now, when i type

```
which phpunit
```

I get

```
/usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

but when I type

```
phpunit --version
```

I get nothing, terminal just returns a new blank line.
From the tutorial i followed, I am supposed to get something like this:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

Did i miss something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try run phpunit without args. If you still don't get any output than you may have an incomplete setup of phpunit or you may have broken it when you moved it to `/usr/local/bin/`

Try moving it back to the mamp folder then create a symlink to the `/usr/local/bin/` folder.

I thik you can doit like this:
    `sudo ln -s path/to/phpunit/executible /usr/local/bin/phpunit`

Hope this helped

Comment: when i type just 'phpunit', I get the same blank line. No output. Let me try creating a symlink

Comment: no change after adding symlink. I am still getting the blank line on phpunit and phpunit --version. which phpunit returns the usr/local/bin/phpunit

Comment: is the php executable in your path. phpunit requires php. Try running php -v in your user directory. if you get an error that php cannot be found or something, then create a symlink for php in your /usr/local/bin/ folder.

Comment: yes. I do have the path setup correctly. php -v returns this "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php"

Comment: I think you meant `which php` returns "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php".